# Unity VR: How to draw camera on top of VRSettings.showDeviceView mirroring

Tags: unity, camera, virtual-reality, overlay

We're using VRSettings.showDeviceView = true to mirror the VR display to the main window. We also have a camera that we'd like to draw over top of the main window's mirrored VR image. This other camera renders an overlay for people who are watching the mirrored VR view.

Right now the overlay camera has a depth of 5 and the VR camera has a depth of 0, but as far as I can tell I think the overlay camera of depth 5 is being overwritten by the mirror drawn by showDeviceView = true.

Anyone know an easy trick to get this behaviour?

Thanks for your time,

Allen

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the effect by disabling mirroring (VRSettings.showDeviceView = false), and then setting up an additional camera that displays to the main window. Make the second camera a child of the VR camera (with the same size, FOV, etc.), and then set up any overlay objects on their own layer that is not viewable to the VR camera.